# Storyboard Triggers only once for second condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have a button on which Click, TextBlock MultiDataTrigger runs but on every button click it runs only twice.

**Explaination:** First Default TextBlock Text is Disconnected then there are two MultiDataTriggers out of which satisfies the condition runs and then after another MultiDataTrigger on again button click but after this no Storyboard animation works.

**Textblock**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="abctxt" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Disconnected">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=sbbtn, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=abctxt, Path=Text}" Value="Connected" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource DisconnectedTextChange}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=sbbtn, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=abctxt, Path=Text}" Value="Disconnected" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ConnectedTextChange}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

**Button**

```
<Button x:Name="sbbtn" />
```

**Storyboard**

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ConnectedTextChange" x:Name="ConnectedTextChange">
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" AccelerationRatio="1">
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Connected"/>
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="DisconnectedTextChange" x:Name="DisconnectedTextChange">
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" AccelerationRatio="1">
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Disconnected"/>
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: It seems that the text is hold as “Connected” by the ConnectedTextChange Storyboard so the other Storyboard cannot change it back to “Disconnected”.

Comment: @kennyzx have try this? Any suggestion, what should i do?

Comment: do you have to use an animation (Storyboard)? Or do you just want to change the Text in response to the button click? By default, a Storyboard holds the final value when the Storyboard is completed.

Comment: @kennyzx no! i have to use storyboard, actually i have a another control(Rectangle which slide through margins using storyboard) also which also have same condition as textblock but both textblock and rectangle begin storyboard only once

Comment: @sachinshinde try my approach does same thing correctly.

Comment: @shubhamSahu Thanks' checking your codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking textbox text or button pressed go with single condition `IsChecked`,
Instead of using a simple `Button` use `ToggleButton` and apply your Button style on it.

You can use it like this way:

**Your `TextBlock`**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="abctxt" Text="Disconnected" />
```

**`ToggleButton` Instead of `Button`**

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="sbbtn"> <!-- Also Apply Your Style For making your ToggleButton looks like your Button -->
<ToggleButton.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ConnectedTextChange}" />
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource DisconnectedTextChange}" />
    </EventTrigger>
    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
```

**Your `Storyboard`**

```
<!-- Here i set TargetName also -->
<Storyboard x:Key="ConnectedTextChange" x:Name="ConnectedTextChange" Storyboard.TargetName="abctxt">
<StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" AccelerationRatio="1">
    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Connected"/>
</StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

```
<Storyboard x:Key="DisconnectedTextChange" x:Name="DisconnectedTextChange" Storyboard.TargetName="abctxt">
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" AccelerationRatio="1">
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Disconnected"/>
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks' its works as intended, also thanks for suggestion of using toggle button.